# Using one set of query parameters to feed into another set of query parameters

Tags: reporting-services, mdx

I wonder if there is a way to have one set of parms feed into another automatically? For example, DS1 has a year and month query parms, both visible. DS2 has an identical year and month query parms, hidden. Is there a way to have the parms from DS1 feed into the parms for DS2 instantly? So when the report is ran both DS1 and DS2 tables are filtered instantaneously?

I saw a similar post on this but the answer was not made clear. Below is my MDX:

```
SELECT NON EMPTY { [Measures].[OPEN],[Measures].[oYTDavg] } ON COLUMNS, 
       NON EMPTY { ([OpenWOs].[FY].[FY].allmembers * [OpenWOs].[FM].[FM].allmembers ) } 
       DIMENSION PROPERTIES member_caption, member_unique_name ON ROWS 
FROM   ( 
              SELECT ( STRTOSET(@openwosfy, constrained) ) 
              ON COLUMNS 
              FROM   [Model])
CELL PROPERTIES VALUE, 
back_color, 
fore_color, 
formatted_value, 
format_string, 
font_name, 
font_size, 
font_flags
```

The first set of parms are @CFY and @CFM. The second set are @OpenWOsFY and @OpenWOsFM.

Comment: If you need both datasets be filtered by the same parameter values why don't you use the same parameters in both datasets?. Also you can set the hidden parameters to take the visible parameters values.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I will try this.